# Minimal resolution of local cohomology module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension $d\geq 1.$ Suppose $\lambda(H_{\mathfrak m}^i(R))<\infty$ for some $0\leq i\leq d-1.$

**Question** *Can we say anything about Betti numbers or  minimal resolution of $H_{\mathfrak m}^i(R)?$*

In particular, can we say anything (whether the Betti numbers are nondecreasing or strictly increasing, direct summand of the syzygies) about $H_{\mathfrak m}^0(R)?$

P.S. Any reference will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Resolution over $R$?

Comment: @HailongDao Yes.

Comment: Is there a motivation for this? In general not much can be said.  For this questio to be interesting, $R$ is not Cohen-Macaulay to begin with, and there is not much known about resolutions over such rings.

Comment: @HailongDao depth R=0.

Comment: Noetherian local ring with dim R>0 and depth R=0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to give a useful answer. I suspect whatever you want/need would be more specific. In particular, details on how such $R$ arises in your research would make it easier to say something more concrete.  But anyhow, there are a couple of remarks and references one can point to.

First, your ring is not Cohen-Macaulay. So any nonzero finite length module would have infinite minimal resolution. Typically, the Betti numbers are expected to have eventual *exponential* growth (see Avramov's surveys from the reference below).

One of the outstanding open problems in this area is whether the Betti numbers are always eventually non-decreasing for any module. There is a related question of whether the syzygies will eventually have full dimension (equals $\dim R$). I don't expect the fact that your modules are local cohomology to make a big difference. Here is a nice [recent paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2013-141-07/S0002-9939-2013-11510-8/home.html) on both questions mentioned above. The bibliography also contains some useful references, particularly the surveys of Avramov.